# Badge - Civic Duty - Vote 300 or more times

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, tag-wiki

What is Badge - Civic Duty
It has simple description "Vote 300 or more times". I'm looking for detail of this badge. I can't see any effect upon down vote question/answers. Does it consider down vote also.